# run libreoffice on background

Tags: libreoffice

i installed libreoffice on ubuntu 13.10 server from terminal

now i have to run it with the command like this

```
/usr/bin/soffice -accept="socket,host=localhost,port=8100;urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager" -headless -norestore -nologo -nofirststartwizard
```

but it dont work correctly

```
peiman@server:~$ sudo netstat -nap | grep office
unix  3      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     2794171  4301/soffice.bin    /tmp/OSL_PIPE_1000_SingleOfficeIPC_84166f53c65d9ded4d416e24fa9b5d8
```

what can be wrong with this?!